# How to enable JMX port for Namenode and Datanode in Hadoop from Ambari

Tags: hadoop, jmx

I am using HDP 3.1.1. I am trying to enable JMX for HDFS by following the below link.

```
https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/data-storage/content/using_jmx_for_accessing_hdfs_metrics.html
```

After restarting the HDFS. again the changes are removing automatically. I tried to add the same lines from Ambari as well At that time HDFS itself is not starting.

Comment: Where did you add them in Ambari? If services don't start, please gather the logs

Comment: I added in Hadoop-env template file

Comment: export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
      -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=xx $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
      -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=xx $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"

Comment: Now it's working but I have 2 name nodes and 3 data nodes how to configure all Hostname in Ambari

Comment: You configure hostnames on the machines themselves, not Ambari. Please create separate post for separate questions

Comment: below commands working now

Answer (score 1):

```
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8004 $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"


export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8006 $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"
```